# Override border style of span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried the following JavaScript/jQuery code to change the border thickness.

But this is not working. Please help me.

```js
//$("span").css({"border":"4px solid green"});
document.getElementById("192.168.42.151:8984_solr").getElementsByClassName("trees_shard1_replica_n1").find("span").style.borderWidth = "thick";
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card a {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.card a span {
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.card a .replicaActive {
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.card a .replicaLeader {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.42.151:8984_solr">
    <a href="#" class="trees_shard1_replica_n1">
      <span class="badge replicaActive">0</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.1.4:8983_solr">
    <a href="#" class="trees_shard1_replica_n3">
      <span class="badge replicaLeader">0</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mirror: https://jsfiddle.net/amitkushwaha1710/asdxfc94/44/

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/eycobms7/ ?

Comment: `.find()` is not a DOM method, but a jQuery method - but you are not working with jQuery objects here. And you neglected to pick a specific element out of the list getElementsByClassName returns first as well. `document.getElementById("192.168.42.151:8984_solr").getElementsByClassName("trees_shard1_replica_n1")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0]` would work, if you really need/want to write code that is that terribly static and inflexible.

Comment: you may find that your id in your javascript code needs to be escaped \\.

Answer (score 2):

Problem in your id attribute, id="192.168.42.151:8984_solr

> id attribute must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

change it and it will work.

you can do something like

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.42.151:8984_solr">
    <a href="#" class="trees_shard1_replica_n1">
      <span class="badge replicaActive">0</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.1.4:8983_solr">
    <a href="#" class="trees_shard1_replica_n3">
      <span class="badge replicaLeader">0</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

$('.card-body').find(".trees_shard1_replica_n1").find("span").css({'color':'red'});
```

Comment: But I can't change it. Any other solution?

Comment: _“Problem in your id attribute”_ - not really, HTML5 has lifted most of those restrictions. https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-id-attribute - at least one character, and no spaces - that’s it.

Comment: @misorude only number will work but when colon after number will not going to work.

Comment: Not true. https://jsfiddle.net/amitkushwaha1710/asdxfc94/44/ This should work in any halfway decent browser that isn’t massively outdated.

Answer (score 1):

*Your code is wrong, Basically It's a mix between `jquery` and `javascript`.*

**Try this: (No `jquery` required)**

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("trees_shard1_replica_n1")[0].querySelector('span').style.borderWidth = "thick";
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card a {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.card a span {
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.card a .replicaActive {
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.card a .replicaLeader {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.42.151:8984_solr">
    <a href="#" class="trees_shard1_replica_n1">
      <span class="badge replicaActive">0</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.1.4:8983_solr">
    <a href="#" class="trees_shard1_replica_n3">
      <span class="badge replicaLeader">0</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not find an element by find() in javascript so you can go the following way

```js
//$("span").css({"border":"4px solid green"});
var solrId = document.getElementById("192.168.42.151:8984_solr").getElementsByClassName('trees_shard1_replica_n1')[0];
solrId.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.borderWidth = "thick";
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card a {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.card a span {
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.card a .replicaActive {
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.card a .replicaLeader {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.42.151:8984_solr">
    <a href="#" class="trees_shard1_replica_n1">
      <span class="badge replicaActive">0</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" id="192.168.1.4:8983_solr">
    <a href="#" class="trees_shard1_replica_n3">
      <span class="badge replicaLeader">0</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope This will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var replicaNodeName="192.168.42.151:8984_solr";
$(document.getElementById(replicaNodeName)).find(".trees_shard1_replica_n1").find("span").css({'border':'4px solid green'});
```